# java trading forex platform charts

Tags: java, platform, trading

Hi I'm trying to make a trading platform with java for a school project but 
I don't have no idea on how to create the candlestick bar chart and also the 
tecnical indicators I've searched thru the Internet but I can't find any good 
tutorial or info about it can someone help please.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, [jfreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) comes to mind.. but i would probably export JSON from the Java app (API endpoint) and then access it with a nice charting library, like [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) or better [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) (bower `highslide-software/highstock-release`).

Comment: HighStock is perfect but it's written in javascript my project have to be only

Comment: HighStock is perfect but it's written in javascript my project have to be only java and for jfreechart I can't find any good tutorial and it seem to be difficult to create a dynamic real-time chart, if can help or provide some code examples I've searched a lot but I only finded static candlestick charts in jfreechart

Comment: This could be of help: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartDynamicDataDemo.htm and also `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/1163786 and http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.html